# Testing my bloc fails when using yield and Either in the mapEventToState

Tags: flutter, testing, dart, yield, bloc

I'm following a course on clean architecture and I'm stuck with the following error.

The following test fails.

```
test('should emit [Error] when the input is invalid', () async {
  final tNumberString = '1';
  when(mockInputConverter.stringToUnsignedInteger(any))
    .thenReturn(Left(InvalidInputFailure()));

  final expected = [
    Empty(),
    Error(message: invalidInput),
   ];
   expectLater(bloc.state, emitsInOrder(expected));

   bloc.add(GetTriviaForConcreteNumberEvent(tNumberString));
});
```

My NumberTriviaBloc is as follows

```
part 'number_trivia_event.dart';
part 'number_trivia_state.dart';

const String serverFailureMessage = 'Server Failure';
const String cacheFailureMessage = 'Cache Failure';
const String invalidInput =
    'Invalid input - the number should be a positive integer';

class NumberTriviaBloc extends Bloc<NumberTriviaEvent, NumberTriviaState> {
  NumberTriviaBloc(
      {@required GetConcreteNumberTrivia concrete,
      @required GetRandomNumberTrivia random,
      @required this.inputConverter})
      : assert(concrete != null),
        assert(random != null),
        assert(inputConverter != null),
        _getConcreteNumberTrivia = concrete,
        _getRandomNumberTrivia = random,
        super(Empty());

  final GetConcreteNumberTrivia _getConcreteNumberTrivia;
  final GetRandomNumberTrivia _getRandomNumberTrivia;
  final InputConverter inputConverter;

  @override
  Stream<NumberTriviaState> mapEventToState(
    NumberTriviaEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is GetTriviaForConcreteNumberEvent) {
      final inputEither =
          inputConverter.stringToUnsignedInteger(event.numberString);

      yield* inputEither.fold(
        (l) async* {
          yield Error(message: invalidInput);
        },
        (r) => throw UnimplementedError(),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Im not that familiar with the bloc patern and the testing mechanisms of streams and states. Im guessing somehow the code isn't executed correctly because the fail message is as follows

```
ERROR: Expected: should do the following in order:
emit an event that Empty:<Empty>
emit an event that Error:<Error>
Actual: Empty:<Empty>
Which: was not a Stream or a StreamQueue
```

Answer (score 3):

So I solved it my self. The code in the question is valid for older versions of dart. At present

```
bloc.state
```

will break the code. Instead

```
bloc
```

should be used to get the state.

The second problem is that it's no longer possible to have a

```
throw UnimplementedError();
```

in the fold method of the Either object. That will cause an exception to be thrown in either case. There has to be some non exception logic in the right function of the fold call.

The modifications are reflected in the code below.

number_trivia_bloc_test.dart

```
test('should emit [Error] when the input is invalid', () async {
  when(mockInputConverter.stringToUnsignedInteger(any))
      .thenReturn(Left(InvalidInputFailure()));

  bloc.add(GetTriviaForConcreteNumberEvent(tNumberString));

  final expected = [
    Error(message: invalidInput),
  ];
  expectLater(bloc, emitsInOrder(expected));
});
```

number_trivia_bloc.dart

```
@override
Stream<NumberTriviaState> mapEventToState(NumberTriviaEvent event,
  ) async* {
  if (event is GetTriviaForConcreteNumberEvent) {
    final inputEither =
      inputConverter.stringToUnsignedInteger(event.numberString);

    yield* inputEither.fold(
      (failure) async* {
        yield Error(message: invalidInput);
      },
      (integer) async* {
        yield null;
      },
    ); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this issue is still relevant.

Actually, there's no need to write streams & yield statements from scratch, as per the newer versions of bloc. But as we are setting the Later calles in testing, we will need to parse a bloc-stream while expecting the result. So, the solution to your code is to use bloc.stream instead of bloc.state which converts the bloc to a bloc stream & yeilds the output in order. Do remember that the stream does not contain the initial/EmptyState(), but all other events are handle in order & hence emitted the same.
Refer to the below code snippet for the proper implementat,

```
This is the bloc file that contains the bloc logic as per the latest versions.

///<inputs an event, outputs the state> => <NumberTriviaEvent, 
NumberTriviaState>
class NumberTriviaBloc extends Bloc<NumberTriviaEvent, NumberTriviaState> {
  final GetConcreteNumberTrivia concreteNumberTrivia;
  final GetRandomNumberTrivia randomNumberTrivia;
  final InputConverter inputConverter;

  NumberTriviaBloc(
      {required this.concreteNumberTrivia,
      required this.randomNumberTrivia,
      required this.inputConverter}) : super(EmptyState()) {
    on<NumberTriviaEvent>((event, emit) async{
        if(event is GetTriviaForConcreteNumber){
          final input = inputConverter.stringToUnsignedInteger(event.numberString);
          input.fold((lFailure){
             emit( const ErrorState(errorMessage: INVALID_INPUT_FAILURE_MESSAGE));
          }, (rSuccess) {
             emit(const LoadedState(numberTrivia: NumberTrivia(text: 'sample test', number: 1)));
          });
        }
    });
  }
}

This is the test file that tests the output over the block that is written above.

    test('should emit [Error] when theres an invalid input', () {
      //  arrange
      when(inputConverter.stringToUnsignedInteger('abc'))
          .thenAnswer((realInvocation) => Left(InvalidInputFailure()));

      //  assert Later
      /// As we will be checking if the emit contains the expected result, we will use expectLater() method in test
      /// which puts the particular test on hold until the data is been emitted(upper limit 30 seconds) & then applies the checks
      expectLater(
        bloc.stream,
        emitsInOrder([
          const ErrorState(errorMessage: INVALID_INPUT_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
          ]));

      //  act
      bloc.add(const GetTriviaForConcreteNumber(numberString: 'abc'));
    });
  });

Learning Source: Reso Coders
```